# subtle change in if statement causing unexpected results

Tags: java, if-statement

why does this work:

```
public String delDel(String str) {
if(str.length() >= 4 && str.substring(1,4).equals("del")){    
        String front = str.substring(0,1);
        String back = str.substring(4, str.length());
        return front + back;
    }
    else{
        return str;
    }
}
```

and this not work:

```
public String delDel(String str) {
if((str.substring(1,4).equals("del")) && str.length() >= 4){    
        String front = str.substring(0,1);
        String back = str.substring(4, str.length());
        return front + back;
    }
    else{
        return str;
    }
}
```

if you notice the difference between the first and second is that str.length() is before the rest of the condition in the first and it is the last condition in the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference demonstrates short-circuit evaluation.

In Java, with the boolean operator `&&`, the second operand won't be evaluated if the first operand is `false`.  This difference is crucial when the second operand being able to be evaluated depends on the first condition being `true`.

First code example:

```
if(str.length() >= 4 && str.substring(1,4).equals("del")){
```

The second part will only be evaluated if the length is 4.  If the length wasn't at least 4, then `substring` would fail with a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  But it can't, because if the length is at least 4, then the call is valid.

Second code example:

```
if((str.substring(1,4).equals("del")) && str.length() >= 4){
```

Now the call to `substring` will be evaluated always, regardless of length, and thus can throw `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Even the [JLS, Section 15.23](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23), has this to say about the subject:

> The conditional-and operator && is like & (§15.22.2), but evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is true.

Additionally, the condition-or operator `||` works similarly, according to the [JLS, Section 15.24](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24):

> The conditional-or operator || operator is like | (§15.22.2), but evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is false.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the second condition may not work is that when the `str` is shorter than `4` characters, you will see a failure in the second condition. The first condition, however, guards against this, because `&&` operator would not evaluate `substr` when the length is less than `4`.